# BadSqlGrammarException:Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Hi all i am getting the above exception when running my code.

Here is my class.

```
    package com.bct.internal.form.model;

    public class Dept {
    public String deptno;
    public String deptname;
    public String location;

    public String getDeptno() {
        return deptno;
    }

    public void setDeptno(String deptno) {
        this.deptno = deptno;
    }

    public String getDeptname() {
        return deptname;
    }

    public void setDeptname(String deptname) {
        this.deptname = deptname;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dept [DEPTNO=" + deptno + ", DNAME=" + deptname + ", LOC=" + location + ", ]";
    }

}
```

and my impl file is

```
@Override
    public Map<String, String> practicelist() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        List<Dept> lang1 = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select * from dept", new DeptMapper());
        for (int i = 0; i < lang1.size(); i++) {
            map.put(lang1.get(i).getDeptno(), lang1.get(i).getDeptname());
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static final class DeptMapper implements RowMapper<Dept> {

        @Override
        public Dept mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Dept dept = new Dept();
            dept.setDeptname(rs.getString("deptname"));
            dept.setDeptno(rs.getString("deptno"));
            dept.setLocation(rs.getString("location"));
            return dept;
        }

    }
```

when trying to execute the code i am getting an error like "ERROR GlobalExceptionHandler.defaultErrorHandler -1 - [URL] : http://localhost:8082/internalhost/userSearch/107
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from dept]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name"

Here is my database table
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIQPq.png)

Comment: Try `select deptname, deptno, location from dept`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank u for the reply:)  I have tried that.. Still showing the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error says invalid column name. Can you validate your database table columns are exactly matching with RowMapper resultset getters.

Comment: @Shanmugapriya change your RowMapper getters like below to sync with you database column names provided in image.   dept.setDeptname(rs.getString("dname"));             dept.setLocation(rs.getString("loc"));

Comment: The issue is solved now.. thank u.. but now its not fetching datas from the table. but it is not showing in the page

Comment: @Shanmugapriya check whether your lang1 List object is loaded with values. If so, it's just fine in DAO layer.